# undefined is not a function (near '...this.state.results.map...')

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new at react native.I have a problem that i've been dealing for a few days.I want to show my data with map.Can you guys show me where i did wrong?
(I think i made mistake in the results inside scrollview)

class Movie extends Component{

```
state= {
    apiurl:'http://www.omdbapi.com/.............................',
    s:'',
    results: [],
    selected:{}
}

 searchFunc(s) {
     this.setState({s: s})
    axios(this.state.apiurl+ "&s="+s).then(response => 
        this.setState({results: response.data.Search[0]}));
        console.log(this.state.results)    
 }
render() {
    return(
        <View style={{flex:1,backgroundColor:'#356292'}}>
        <View
        style={styles.sectionContainer}>      
            <View style={styles.section}>
            <TextInput style={styles.section2}
            onChangeText = {(s) => this.searchFunc({s})}
            value={this.state.s}
            placeholder="Movies,Series.."
             >
                  </TextInput>
                  <TouchableOpacity 
                style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}
                onPress={() => this.searchFunc()}> 
                <Image 
                source ={require('../img/seach.png')}
                style={{width:width*0.05,height:height*0.03}}
                >
                </Image>
                </TouchableOpacity>                          
                </View>                  
        </View>            
        <ScrollView style={styles.scroll}>
            {this.state.results.map(results=>(
                <View key={this.state.results.imdbID} 
                style={styles.scroll2}>
                <Image source={{uri: this.state.results}}
                style={{width:width*0.3, height:height*0.4}}>
                </Image>     
                <Text style={styles.heading}>
                {this.state.results.Title}
                </Text>
                </View>
            ))}

        </ScrollView>
        </View>           

    );
}
```

Comment: is `response.data.Search[0]` an array?

Comment: yes.I wanted to pull the data from url and it came in array.

Comment: so `data.Search` is an array of arrays? and `data.Search[0]` is an array of what?

Comment: I wrote [0] to see what was coming and than i forget this:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments from your original post, i'm guessing `response.data.Search[0]` is also an array. If so your results state update is okay. Otherwise you should set the results state to  `response.data.Search`.

Other problem I noticed in your code is in the map function, you are mapping the array with each item refering to the result variable, but in your jsx, you are trying to access the  `results` state variable. It should be

```js
<ScrollView style={styles.scroll}> 
  {
    this.state.results.map(result => (
      <View 
        key={result.imdbID} 
        style={styles.scroll2}
      >
         <Image 
            source={{uri: result.image}} // use correct key from result object
            style={{width:width*0.3, height:height*0.4}}
         />
         <Text style={styles.heading}>{result.Title}</Text>
      </View>
     ))
  }
</ScrollView>
```

Also in your Textinput `onChangeText` callback function, you dont have to pass that value as an object. You can change it to

```js
<TextInput 
  style={styles.section2}
  onChangeText={(s) => this.searchFunc(s)}
  value={this.state.s}
  placeholder="Movies,Series.."
/>
```

Comment: oh thank you so much i didn't noticed that :D

Answer (score 0):

I quess you are supposed to pass `Search` to the state and not the `Search[0]`, which is the object and not `map`, the reason `map` function is not working on it.

```
axios(this.state.apiurl+ "&s="+s).then(response => 
        this.setState({results: response.data.Search}));
        console.log(this.state.results)
```

Coincidently, I have created an app using same movie API, you can find it here: [Github Repo, Movie App](https://github.com/TheKetan2/movie-app-react-starckoverflow-answer)

Comment: thank you :) I wrote [0] to see  what was coming.I fixed this error now i have different error.I'm new at react and this is my first project.Your project looks like cool!

Comment: one more suggestion, if you are trying to deploy then change URL to ```https://www.omdbapi.com/....``` instead of ```'http://www.omdbapi.com/``` one. And you can accept this answer if found helpful :) finished app: https://theketan2.github.io/movie-app-react-starckoverflow-answer/

Comment: yes it's helpful thank you. Your app looks very good! I'm trying to do it similar